# Messenger bot that reacts to all messages

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I am working on a messenger bot for a group, that reacts to all messages that people type, unfortunately I don't have much experience with the messenger API, so I can't do it on my own. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details to help you with your question

1. Start with the article that helps with process understanding, for
   example: 
   [Facebook Bots for fun and profit](https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/facebook-bots-for-fun-and-profit-490245c3797c)
2. Explore the official Facebook API documentation
3. Choose methods you would like to implement
4. Using programming language you know, try to implement this methods step-by-step, also you can find some working examples on GitHub
5. While having issues, try to find answers here on Stackoverflow, or google it - most of your questions are already solved by somebody

Good luck with your bot!